# How to replace a particular character in java

Tags: java

I have a json string like this.

```
{"page_1":"{\"city\":\"Delhi\",\"locality\":\"Defence Colony\",\"Name_of_Person\":\"test\",\"User_email_address\":\"test1@gmail.com\",\"user_phone_number\":\"\",\"sub_locality\":\"\",\"street_name\":\"qwe\",\"home_plot_no\":\"22\",\"pin_code\":\"\",\"project_society_build_name\":\"\",\"landmark_reference_1\":\"\",\"landmark_reference_2\":\"\",\"No_of_Schools\":20,\"No_of_Hospitals\":20,\"No_of_Metro\":5,\"No_of_Mall\":20,\"No_of_Park\":20,\"Distance_of_schools\":1.36,\"Distance_of_Hospitals\":0.77,\"Distance_of_Metro\":1.32,\"Distance_of_Mall\":0.98,\"Distance_of_Park\":2.6,\"lat\":28.5726334,\"lng\":77.23251,\"ipinfo\":{\"ip\":\"123.63.86.161\",\"hostname\":\"No Hostname\",\"city\":\"New Delhi\",\"region\":\"National Capital Territory of Delhi\",\"country\":\"IN\",\"loc\":\"28.6000,77.2000\",\"org\":\"AS55410 C48 Okhla Industrial Estate, New Delhi-110020\"}}","page_2":"{\"home_type\":\"Flat\",\"area\":\"1500\",\"beds\":\"4 BHK\",\"bath_rooms\":2,\"building_age\":\"1\",\"floors\":2,\"balcony\":2,\"amenities\":\"regular\",\"amenities_options\":{\"gated_security\":\"\",\"physical_security\":\"\",\"cctv_camera\":\"\",\"controll_access\":\"\",\"elevator\":\"\",\"power_back_up\":true,\"parking\":\"\",\"partial_parking\":\"\",\"onsite_maintenance_store\":\"\",\"open_garden\":\"\",\"party_lawn\":\"\",\"amenities_balcony\":\"\",\"club_house\":\"\",\"fitness_center\":\"\",\"swimming_pool\":\"\",\"party_hall\":\"\",\"tennis_court\":\"\",\"basket_ball_court\":\"\",\"squash_coutry\":\"\",\"amphi_theatre\":\"\",\"business_center\":\"\",\"jogging_track\":\"\",\"convinience_store\":\"\",\"guest_rooms\":\"\"},\"interior\":\"regular\",\"interior_options\":{\"tiles\":\"\",\"marble\":true,\"wooden\":true,\"modular_kitchen\":\"\",\"partial_modular_kitchen\":\"\",\"gas_pipe\":\"\",\"intercom_system\":\"\",\"air_conditioning\":\"\",\"partial_air_conditioning\":\"\",\"wardrobe\":\"\",\"sanitation_fixtures\":\"\",\"false_ceiling\":\"\",\"partial_false_ceiling\":\"\",\"recessed_lighting\":\"\"},\"location\":\"regular\",\"location_options\":{\"good_view\":\"\",\"transporation_hub\":\"\",\"shopping_center\":\"\",\"hospital\":\"\",\"school\":\"\",\"ample_parking\":\"\",\"park\":\"\",\"temple\":\"\",\"bank\":\"\",\"less_congestion\":\"\",\"less_pollution\":\"\"},\"maintenance\":\"\",\"maintenance_value\":\"\",\"near_by\":{\"school\":\"\",\"hospital\":\"\",\"mall\":\"\",\"park\":\"\",\"metro\":\"\",\"Near_by_school\":\"FOSTIIMA Business School \\\/ 1.35 km\",\"Near_by_hospital\":\"Institute Rotary Cancer Hospital \\\/ 2.16 km\",\"Near_by_mall\":\"Chandi Plaza \\\/ 2.68 km\",\"Near_by_park\":\"Central Park \\\/ 2.57 km\",\"Near_by_metro\":\"City Of Lajpat Nagar \\\/ 0.98 km\"},\"city\":\"Delhi\",\"locality\":\"Defence Colony\",\"token\":\"000b3a96b0e6790fd5e3b24831ec4d4d\"}"}
```

I want to replace a particular characters like this.

```
"page_1":"{"city" change to "page_1":{"city"
"}}", change to "}},
"page_2":"{"home_type" change to "page_2":{"home_type"
"}"} change to  "}}
append  }  at last
```

I tried like this

```
String newString = jsonFormattedString.substring(0, 10) + "" + s.substring(0,0);
```

But the above code not works for me.Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Apparently aou cut the first ten characters out of the string, append nothing, and append nothing again? Did you try String.replaceAll?

Comment: "code not works" is not an adequate problem description.

Answer (score 1):

you use replace method in java
first replace all slash

```
 newString.replace('\\', '');
```

second replace qouate

```
newString.replace("\"{", "}");´
```

Comment: no man. my question is I want to replace a particular characters like this. "page_1":"{"city" as "page_1":{"city"

Comment: I have "page_1":"{"city" right.I want to replace a particular quotes like this "page_1":{"city". I removed quotes before braces.

Comment: Well, then you should use something like this: ´s.replace("\"{", "}");´. This is what you mentioned, remove quotes before (curly) braces.

Comment: `newString.replace('\', '');` is invalid java, even when in a character literal, you still need to escape the `\`, try `newString.replace('\\', '');`

Answer (score 0):

Actually you have to replace all "{ with { and all }" with } 
 Here is the code.

```
String halfDone = jsonFormattedString.replaceAll("\"{", "{");
String done = halfDone.replaceAll("}\"", "}");
```

Comment: [`replace`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence%29), not [`replaceAll`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29). `replaceAll` is for regular expressions.